# speeding up drawing of an OverlayView

Tags: objective-c, ios5, core-graphics, mapkit, overlay

I'm drawing an Image (2.5 MB, PNG image data, 1240 x 1240, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced) on a MKMapView by Subclassing MKPolygonView and overriding the drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext:-method as follows:

```
-(void) drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context {

CGRect theRect           = [self rectForMapRect:overlayRect];
CGRect clipRect     = [self rectForMapRect:mapRect];


CGContextClipToRect(context, clipRect);

CGContextDrawImage(context, theRect, imageReference);
```

}

`overlayRect` is an `MKMapRect` defining the position and size of the image on the map (hard coded and initialized in `initWithOverlay:`)
`imageReference` holds a reference to the image, loaded in an UIImage and obtained by calling `CGImage` on the `UIImage` instance (also in `initWithOverlay:`)

My MKMapView takes between 8-14 seconds to draw the image on the map the first time, taking again about the same time when zooming in to redraw the tiles with better resolution.
That seems really long and i'm wondering if I'm doing anything fundamentally wrong as it is my first time with MapKit.

Comment: It's not a 2.5 MB image it's a 1024x1024 8bit/color image. It takes time to decompress such a big image. I encourage you to read the short ibook from Bill Dudney on loading images (in the iBookStore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tile images to improve the performance. Apple used this technique in the WWDC 2010. You can see the example here: https://github.com/klokantech/Apple-WWDC10-TileMap.

Also in this blog explain the process: http://shawnsbits.com/blog/2010/12/23/mapkit-overlays-session-1-overlay-map/

Comment: Thanks! I didn't consider this as the Image already gets rendered as what looks like tiles. I'm gonna give a try, though, and be back :)